# comparing strings according to dictionary appearance order in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'm having hard time figuring how to do this:
In my HW I need to compare between 2 strings that might contain numbers too,
Here are some examples:

```
A>a
ad>abc
Abc>U2
```

Is there any way to do it when i have both strings in variables ?!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want something like:

```
if [[ "$string1" < "$string2" ]]; 
then
   comparison='<' ; 
else
   if [[ "$string1" < "$string2" ]]; 
   then 
      comparison='>'
   else
      comparison='='
   fi
fi
echo "${string1}${comparison}${string2}"
```

But please note that it highly depends on your LOCALE !

I'd recommand to add, at first line of the script, a change of locale to ensure you use the proper one. For example:

```
LC_ALL='C'
```

(see also : LC_COLLATE, LC_LANG, etc. if you only need a specific locale for specific tests. But changing LC_ALL changes them all)

You can know the supported (installed) locales with:

```
locale -a
```

and the currently used locale with:

```
locale
```

Answer (score 2):

To compare strings, the usual way is `[[ $var1 < $var2 ]]` .

Comment: In addition, at least in the ASCII collating sequence, `A<a`. In other locales, you might have `A==a`... So more specificity would definitely be a good thing...

Comment: after asking my teacher its called lexicographic order , any idea ?

Comment: choroba's answer will produce a lexicographic comparison of the two strings, for whatever lexical order your current locale uses - for an ASCII locale, you have the capital latin alphabet followed by the lowercase one (ABCD...abcd...). For some other locales, you have capitals being considered equivalent to lowercase (AaBbCcDd...); yet others have the letters in different orders (ABCD... vs ABGD...) or have fewer or extra letters and/or letters with various diacritic marks, or may not even use the latin alphabet...